# Sum of data at each row in different column in sql

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I need to create a different column of total sales which is the total of the sales units till that row. As our sales unit will increase, the total sales will increase row by row. I have attached the image to get the clear idea.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: It looks like quite complicated solution. Can you please provide me any simple solution to this problem? Also, I can only use proc sql or SAS to find solution. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is use to use of subquery with `correlation` approach

```
select *,  
         (select sum(sales) from table where product = t.product and ? <= t.?) TotalSales
from table t
```

However, you would required `?` (i.e. `rowid` or `id`) column that could specify your column ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query, which adds up all the sales upto that `rowId` and for the specific product.

```
select (select sum(ids)
         from TBL_NAME T1 
         where T1.rowid <= TBL_NAME.rowid  and PRODUCT=TBL_NAME.PRODUCT
       ) as TotalSales     
 from TBL_NAME;
```

Following answer is for Oracle DB, you can understand the query and easily convert it to the product you want.